# calculating the occurrence of each column values in DataTable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, count, group-by

I have a data table, which contains set of Attributes such as (Weather, Wind, ...etc)

I wanna count the occurrence of each of the values in each column or Attribute.

this is my DataTable:

[image: input]

the output will be something like:

```
Weather:
   sunny : 120

   cloudy : 200

   rainy : 300
Wind:
   slight : 200

   strong : 120
```

I have no idea where to start, any idea can save my day

thank you

Comment: You need to use Group By. You must call it seperately for each columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy.

This one will create an array of anonymous objects with the properties `Key` and `Count`

```
// Add to the project a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
// Add a "using System.Data" to the cs file

// dt is your DataTable

var res = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
           group x by (string)x["Weather"] into y
           select new { Key = y.Key, Count = y.Count() }).ToArray();
```

This one will create an array of `Tuple<string, int>` containing the same data.

```
var res2 = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group x by (string)x["Weather"] into y
            select Tuple.Create(y.Key, y.Count())).ToArray();
```

Remember to read the comments!

Clearly you'll have to repeat everything for every column.